# cocos2d progress bar

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

HI all,

i am developing a puzzle game in iPhone using cocos2d.I need a progress bar (like uiprogress bar) to show the game progress time.But i can't find any good example...

can anyone tell me the way???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well....i get a better solution...here is my code

```
CCProgressFromTo *to1 = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:levelTimeLimit from:100 to:0];
    timeBar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithFile:@"Bar.png"];
    timeBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR;
    [timeBar setPosition:ccp(384,84)];
    [self addChild:timeBar];
    [timeBar runAction:to1];
```

there is a class called CCProgressTimer in latest version of cocos2d..

thanks

Comment: Great answer! Additional thanks for incorporating CCProgressFromTo action - wouldn't have known about it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CCSprite that you set the width of using

```
yourSprite.scaleX = 0.5 //This goes between 0.0 and 1.0.
```

You will have to calculate the required width, percentage and scaleX-factor manually but its pretty simple. I did my fiend hp bar implementation like this:

```
-(void)decreaseHp:(float)hpIn {
    self.hp = self.hp-hpIn;    //Decrease HP by specified amount.
    float p = (self.hp*100)/self.maxHp;    //Calculate new hp percentage.
    self.hpBar.scaleX = p/100;    //Convert percentage to a factor between 0 and 1.
}
```

self is the Fiend object and hpBar is a simple CCSprite with anchor ccp(0,0).

You you don't want you progress bar to stretch, but move instead, you will have to mask it with something and update its position instead of scaleX.